# WPF Designer: "No document Root"

Tags: wpf

I'm creating a WPF Application which worked really good until now. I create it with Visual Studio 2019 Professional.

But since a few changes in a Usercontrol I have a curios issue. When I change something in the XAML it changes in the Designer.

But when I start it now, the Design View disappear an I only see this: No document root.

[image: No document root]

I have no idea whats the problem. Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: Is your XAML still valid?

Comment: Yes, I've got no errors. And I can start it and open the UserControl. Everthing works fine expect the designer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. But not the reason of my problem. We use git, so I deleted my solution and cloned it again. And then it worked.

But I have no idea what went wrong before, it was exactly the same code.